# Arduino Wire program seems to stop reading bytes after first i2c payload

Tags: arduino, i2c, lcd

I am trying to write a program that receives string data from i2c and displays it on an LCD.  The first time data is received to the arduino, it renders it, however subsequent i2c payloads are ignored.  My onReceive function has a status line display on the second line of the lcd which display the `seconds()` field from the timer chip.  The seconds number does not seem to increment.  However, the per-second dot flash as rendered in loop() does continue to blink, so the mcu is not frozen.

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>    
#include <Wire.h>    
#include <Time.h>    
LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 10, 5, 4, 3, 2);

void setup()
{
  Wire.begin(4);                // join i2c bus with address #4
  Wire.onReceive(receiveEvent); // register event
  lcd.begin(16,2);              // columns, rows.  use 16,2 for a 16x2 LCD, etc.
  lcd.clear();                  // start with a blank screen

}

void loop()
{
  lcd.setCursor(15,1);
  if (second() % 2 == 0)
    lcd.write(".");
    else
    lcd.write(" ");


  delay(100);

}

void receiveEvent(int howMany)
{

  //char buf[howMany];
  int i=0;
  char output[16];

  lcd.clear();
  while(Wire.available())
  {
    char c = Wire.read(); // receive byte as a character
    lcd.setCursor(i,0);
    lcd.write(c);
    i++;
    //buf[i++]=c;
    //buf[i+1]=0;
  }
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  sprintf(output,"s%dNB%dI%d",second(),howMany,i);
  lcd.write(output);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Arduino may be trapped in here:

```
while(Wire.available())
 {
  //...
```

Use:

```
if(Wire.available() > 0) {
 //stuff
}
```

instead.

Comment: thank you, I will try this tonight and update the question as necessary!